# Getting data from Oracle table where two columns equal separate lists

Tags: python, sql, oracle, filtering

I am pulling data using python, from an ORACLE table.  I can pull the rows I need for one of the lists using

```
office_list = [aaa, aab, aac, aad]
```

&& the actual list is much longer

```py
"""
SELECT * 
  FROM (
        SELECT distinct(id) as id, 
               office, 
               cym,
               type
          FROM oracle1.table1
         WHERE office IN ({0})
        ) 
""".format("'" + "','".join([str(i) for i in office_list]) + "'")
```

What I can't figure out is how to also include another filter from a different list.

In this case it is a list of types

```
type_list = [type1, type2, type3, type4]
```

Any help would be appreciated.
thanks

Comment: Don't use string concatenation to build queries. If someone decides to pass in `office_list = ["',(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM secrets_table WHERE username = 'Admin' and password_hash='ABCDEF'),'"]` then you have a problem.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I forgot to mention that I have to use an intermediary program to access the data...so the string format is needed.  Sergey's response worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"""select * from(
    select
                     distinct(id) as id, 
                     office, 
                     cym,
                     type
                     from oracle1.table1
                     where office in ({0})
                       and type in ({1})
                 ) 
""".format("'" + "','".join(office_list) + "'", "'" + "','".join(type_list) + "'")
```

Comment: Don't use string concatenation to build queries. If someone decides to pass in `type_list = ["',(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM secrets_table WHERE username = 'Admin' and password_hash='ABCDEF'),'"]` then you have a problem.

Comment: SQL injection problem is a separate issue))

PS: besides, they may not exist, you do not know how the list is formed by type_list. It does not have to be a form on a website, and forms must be handled accordingly.

Comment: Anyway data should be passed as data (=bind variables), not as part of SQL statement *text*. Concatenated statement also imposes very high parsing time.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  The string is required to access the data...I forgot to include that...there is an intermediary program that uses the string in the format I gave.  Sergey's replay worked great.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In cx_oracle, [pass collections to the query](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html#binding-multiple-values-to-a-sql-where-in-clause). Using bind variables will help to prevent SQL injection attacks and will allow the SQL engine to re-use execution plans for different lists which will give greater performance (conversely, using string concatenation would make your code vulnerable to SQL injection attacks and not allow re-use of the execution plans).

In SQL:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE string_list AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(25);
/
```

In Python:

```py
list_type = connection.gettype("STRING_LIST")

office_list = list_type.newobject()
office_list.extend(["aaa", "aab", "aac", "aad"])

type_list = list_type.newobject()
type_list.extend(["xxx", "xxy", "xxz", "xyz"])

cursor.execute(
    """SELECT DISTINCT
           id,         -- DISTINCT is NOT a function.
           office, 
           cym,
           type
    FROM   oracle1.table1
    WHERE  office in (SELECT column_value FROM TABLE(:1))
    AND    type   in (SELECT column_value FROM TABLE(:2))""",
    [office_list, type_list],
)
for row in cursor:
    print(row)
```

---

You may be able to simplify the `WHERE` clause to:

```sql
WHERE  office MEMBER OF TABLE(:1)
AND    type   MEMBER OF TABLE(:2)
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I forgot to mention that I have to use an intermediary program to access the data...so the string format is needed.  Sergey's response worked.