# oracle SQL select a large list of values through python

Tags: python, sql, oracle

Good Morning

I have a list of values provided through PGSQL database. These values are F_NAME, M_NAME, L_NAME, DOB, DEPT_CD, HOURLY.

They are of type:

| F_NAME | M_NAME | L_NAME | DOB | DEPT_CD | HOURLY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VARCHAR(50) | VARCHAR(1) | VARCHAR(50) | DATE | INTEGER | VARCHAR(1) |

I get an average about 8000 rows of data to work with at a time.
This data needs to be used to make a comparison in an Oracle database, which holds the complete HR data.

Using python I would like to a make a query similar to this:

`select * from emp_master where (f_name, m_name, l_name, dob, dept_cd, hourly) in (select * from oracle_tabe_type(table_object_name)`

To that end I have made a TYPE T_RECORD of OBJECT:

```
reate or replace TYPE t_record IS OBJECT (
F_NAME VARCHAR(50), 
M_NAME VARCHAR(1), 
L_NAME VARCHAR(50), 
DOB DATE, 
DEPT_CD INTEGER, 
HOURLY VARCHAR(1)
);
```

beyond this, i really do not know what to do. I know that unlike PGSQL/python I can not use a list  [] to make select with executemany.

I would appreciate any help in accomplishing this task. Thank you very much.

Comment: Is your RDBMS Oracle or PostGreSQL? AFAIK, IN() cannot be used like that. Perhaps you need EXISTS(). `select * from emp_master where EXISTS (select * from oracle_tabe_type(table_object_name)`. Possibly will have to specify fields instead of wildcards.

Comment: the RDBMS is mainly oracle, some data is stored in PostGreSQL. Regarding IN(), I have used this when checking for a list of single values. A sample of this is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69891564/getting-data-from-oracle-table-where-two-columns-equal-separate-lists. Mine is where it is not a list of single values, but a list of multiple values as described in my question.

Comment: I don't follow..You get 8000 rows as what? you say you want to use python to (I think) check if these rows exist in an oracle table but then you create an oracle object whose purpose is unclear given your previous expressed desire to use python. you may be looking for intersect https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/The-UNION-ALL-INTERSECT-MINUS-Operators.html#GUID-B64FE747-586E-4513-945F-80CB197125EE

Comment: I use Access and the IN() operator does not work with multiple fields. If it works with Oracle, great.

Comment: For the record, since it isn't currently stated anywhere in this question & discussion, use the python-oracledb driver to connect to Oracle Database: https://oracle.github.io/python-oracledb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what you are trying to do with Python or PostgreSQL. However, you can trivially do what you are asking purely in Oracle SQL:

First create the types:

```sql
CREATE TYPE emp_rec IS OBJECT (
  F_NAME VARCHAR(50), 
  M_NAME VARCHAR(1), 
  L_NAME VARCHAR(50), 
  DOB DATE, 
  DEPT_CD INTEGER, 
  HOURLY VARCHAR(1)
);

CREATE TYPE emp_trec IS TABLE OF emp_rec;
```

Then, if you have the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE emp_master (
  F_NAME  VARCHAR2(50),
  M_NAME  VARCHAR2(1),
  L_NAME  VARCHAR(50),
  DOB     DATE,
  DEPT_CD INTEGER,
  HOURLY  VARCHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO emp_master(f_name, m_name, l_name, dob, dept_cd, hourly)
SELECT 'Alice', 'A', 'Abbot', DATE '1970-01-01', 1, 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Betty', 'B', 'Baron', DATE '1980-01-01', 2, 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Carol', 'C', 'Count', DATE '1990-01-01', 3, 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Debra', 'D', 'Duke',  DATE '2000-01-01', 4, 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Emily', 'E', 'Earl',  DATE '2010-01-01', 5, 'Y' FROM DUAL;
```

Then you can use the query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   emp_master
WHERE  (f_name, m_name, l_name, dob, dept_cd, hourly) in (
         SELECT *
         FROM   TABLE(
                  emp_trec(
                    emp_rec('Alice', 'A', 'Abbot', DATE '1970-01-01', 1, 'Y'),
                    emp_rec('Carol', 'C', 'Count', DATE '1990-01-01', 3, 'Y'),
                    emp_rec('Emily', 'E', 'Earl',  DATE '2010-01-01', 5, 'Y')
                  )
                )
       );
```

Which outputs:

| F_NAME | M_NAME | L_NAME | DOB | DEPT_CD | HOURLY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alice | A | Abbot | 1970-01-01 00:00:00 | 1 | Y |
| Carol | C | Count | 1990-01-01 00:00:00 | 3 | Y |
| Emily | E | Earl | 2010-01-01 00:00:00 | 5 | Y |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/eB6rCsqp)

---

If you are trying to compare data in a PostgreSQL table and an Oracle table then you probably do not want to read the data from the PostgreSQL database into in-memory python data structures and then dynamically generate an Oracle query using `OBJECT` types.

Instead, create a `DATABASE LINK` from Oracle to PostgreSQL and query the Oracle database using a `JOIN` to the database-linked table.

Something like:

```sql
SELECT e.*
FROM   emp_master e
       INNER JOIN remote_table_name@postgresql_dblink p
       ON (   e.f_name  = p.f_name
          AND e.m_name  = p.m_name
          AND e.l_name  = p.l_name
          AND e.dob     = p.dob
          AND e.dept_cd = p.dept_cd
          AND e.hourly  = p.hourly );
```

or

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   emp_master e
WHERE  EXISTS(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   remote_table_name@postgresql_dblink p
         WHERE  e.f_name  = p.f_name
         AND    e.m_name  = p.m_name
         AND    e.l_name  = p.l_name
         AND    e.dob     = p.dob
         AND    e.dept_cd = p.dept_cd
         AND    e.hourly  = p.hourly
       );
```

Comment: I can accept this as an answer, however where i work there is no direct connection between the corporate RDBMS (oracle) and the other database (PostGreSQL), which is used for adhoc work.